# Python/VPN: How to resume the python script automatically as soon as the VPN reconnects?

Tags: python, operating-system, vpn

I have a python script (xyz.py) that I run through the command prompt. But sometimes I face the issue of VPN disconnection due to some reason and once it reconnects, I re-run the whole program again. My question is that don't we have any method which helps to resume the python code automatically from where it was lost the VPN connection, without any manual intervention. This will help to avoid monitoring the code frequently. Below is my code but it reads from the start if there is any disconnection. Please suggest.

import subprocess

```
filename = 'xyx.py'
while True:
    p = subprocess.Popen('python '+filename, shell=True).wait()
    """#if your there is an error from running 'xyz.py', 
    the while loop will be repeated, 
    otherwise the program will break from the loop"""
    if p != 0:
       continue
    else:
       break
```

Comment: You run your code in a loop and if a network error occurs you sleep for some time and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how the code will detect the network loss? Do we have any module or method

Comment: By trying to make a connection and seeing if it works. Just checking if the interface is up does not verify that a connection is possible.

Comment: Hi. I edited my question. Please let me know if anyone has method to resolve the question in the post.